# Animate finding the middle (hypercube edition)

Tags: code-golf, array

[1d version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100411/animate-finding-the-middle)

Given a multidimensional array of positive integers where all dimensions are the same length, animate finding the centre of it.

Simply output the array, then remove the first and last items of every array within it and output it, until the length of each dimension is less than 3 and can't have the first and last removed.

For example, with this 2-dimensonal array:

```
[ [7, 2, 3, 6, 4], 
  [2, 4, 9, 9, 8], 
  [7, 3, 1, 9, 8], 
  [9, 1, 7, 6, 9],  
  [4, 3, 4, 8, 5] ]
```

You'd output the array, then remove the first and last of each to output this:

```
[ [4, 9, 9], 
  [3, 1, 9],
  [1, 7, 6] ]
```

And finally output just this:

```
[ [ 1 ] ]
```

Output format can be as an array of multidimensional arrays, each array printed separately, etcetera.

You may output a trailing empty list, and you don't have to output the original array.

### Testcases

```
[[[4, 6, 7], [1, 6, 8], [3, 3, 4]], [[9, 2, 8], [4, 9, 4], [6, 3, 9]], [[3, 7, 8], [4, 3, 6], [2, 8, 2]]] -> 
[[[4, 6, 7], [1, 6, 8], [3, 3, 4]], [[9, 2, 8], [4, 9, 4], [6, 3, 9]], [[3, 7, 8], [4, 3, 6], [2, 8, 2]]]
[[[9]]]

[[[6, 5, 9, 4], [8, 8, 5, 1], [9, 3, 1, 6], [1, 7, 7, 9]], [[8, 3, 7, 2], [6, 6, 9, 4], [5, 6, 8, 3], [2, 1, 9, 9]], [[4, 9, 6, 9], [6, 9, 3, 7], [3, 6, 8, 2], [7, 5, 8, 6]], [[8, 6, 2, 1], [3, 5, 9, 5], [2, 6, 1, 3], [3, 6, 3, 9]]] ->
[[[6, 5, 9, 4], [8, 8, 5, 1], [9, 3, 1, 6], [1, 7, 7, 9]], [[8, 3, 7, 2], [6, 6, 9, 4], [5, 6, 8, 3], [2, 1, 9, 9]], [[4, 9, 6, 9], [6, 9, 3, 7], [3, 6, 8, 2], [7, 5, 8, 6]], [[8, 6, 2, 1], [3, 5, 9, 5], [2, 6, 1, 3], [3, 6, 3, 9]]]
[[[6, 9], [6, 8]], [[9, 3], [6, 8]]]

[[[[[5, 1, 6], [8, 2, 9], [9, 2, 4]], [[7, 1, 8], [1, 1, 5], [6, 9, 4]], [[3, 6, 6], [9, 9, 9], [4, 2, 5]]], [[[9, 9, 8], [7, 2, 7], [1, 2, 6]], [[3, 1, 8], [1, 7, 9], [6, 9, 2]], [[6, 6, 1], [6, 8, 8], [2, 5, 6]]], [[[9, 5, 3], [3, 6, 9], [8, 8, 7]], [[4, 6, 4], [8, 7, 9], [8, 6, 7]], [[2, 4, 1], [4, 5, 2], [8, 7, 8]]]], [[[[8, 1, 6], [1, 4, 4], [7, 6, 6]], [[9, 9, 9], [8, 1, 7], [9, 2, 4]], [[9, 5, 7], [1, 4, 8], [3, 8, 1]]], [[[3, 8, 1], [8, 7, 6], [1, 5, 7]], [[8, 5, 1], [7, 2, 1], [7, 1, 3]], [[1, 2, 6], [4, 3, 7], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[8, 1, 1], [7, 5, 2], [9, 3, 6]], [[2, 1, 5], [1, 3, 3], [5, 5, 2]], [[7, 6, 2], [9, 5, 7], [3, 8, 1]]]], [[[[5, 8, 9], [7, 2, 5], [3, 9, 7]], [[7, 8, 7], [3, 4, 1], [4, 1, 3]], [[3, 8, 6], [7, 7, 9], [8, 4, 8]]], [[[7, 5, 4], [8, 1, 7], [9, 9, 1]], [[1, 1, 8], [2, 3, 7], [9, 5, 4]], [[2, 2, 6], [8, 8, 2], [1, 3, 6]]], [[[7, 2, 7], [1, 7, 3], [8, 3, 9]], [[6, 1, 4], [8, 3, 8], [8, 9, 5]], [[5, 7, 2], [9, 7, 6], [1, 3, 4]]]]] ->
[[[[[5, 1, 6], [8, 2, 9], [9, 2, 4]], [[7, 1, 8], [1, 1, 5], [6, 9, 4]], [[3, 6, 6], [9, 9, 9], [4, 2, 5]]], [[[9, 9, 8], [7, 2, 7], [1, 2, 6]], [[3, 1, 8], [1, 7, 9], [6, 9, 2]], [[6, 6, 1], [6, 8, 8], [2, 5, 6]]], [[[9, 5, 3], [3, 6, 9], [8, 8, 7]], [[4, 6, 4], [8, 7, 9], [8, 6, 7]], [[2, 4, 1], [4, 5, 2], [8, 7, 8]]]], [[[[8, 1, 6], [1, 4, 4], [7, 6, 6]], [[9, 9, 9], [8, 1, 7], [9, 2, 4]], [[9, 5, 7], [1, 4, 8], [3, 8, 1]]], [[[3, 8, 1], [8, 7, 6], [1, 5, 7]], [[8, 5, 1], [7, 2, 1], [7, 1, 3]], [[1, 2, 6], [4, 3, 7], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[8, 1, 1], [7, 5, 2], [9, 3, 6]], [[2, 1, 5], [1, 3, 3], [5, 5, 2]], [[7, 6, 2], [9, 5, 7], [3, 8, 1]]]], [[[[5, 8, 9], [7, 2, 5], [3, 9, 7]], [[7, 8, 7], [3, 4, 1], [4, 1, 3]], [[3, 8, 6], [7, 7, 9], [8, 4, 8]]], [[[7, 5, 4], [8, 1, 7], [9, 9, 1]], [[1, 1, 8], [2, 3, 7], [9, 5, 4]], [[2, 2, 6], [8, 8, 2], [1, 3, 6]]], [[[7, 2, 7], [1, 7, 3], [8, 3, 9]], [[6, 1, 4], [8, 3, 8], [8, 9, 5]], [[5, 7, 2], [9, 7, 6], [1, 3, 4]]]]]
[[[[[2]]]]]

[[[[1, 8, 1, 7, 8], [2, 6, 6, 2, 8], [9, 4, 2, 3, 3], [1, 9, 5, 8, 5], [6, 3, 9, 2, 2]], [[8, 2, 5, 5, 3], [3, 3, 8, 6, 6], [3, 3, 5, 6, 6], [4, 2, 5, 3, 6], [2, 2, 5, 5, 4]], [[4, 4, 1, 9, 7], [4, 3, 4, 3, 8], [3, 7, 1, 7, 7], [1, 2, 7, 5, 6], [5, 6, 5, 4, 6]], [[7, 8, 9, 7, 2], [9, 4, 9, 9, 2], [3, 1, 9, 2, 9], [3, 5, 8, 4, 7], [3, 3, 5, 9, 9]], [[5, 6, 2, 4, 3], [2, 9, 6, 6, 1], [6, 8, 2, 9, 7], [5, 2, 1, 8, 4], [7, 7, 9, 6, 1]]], [[[2, 2, 8, 1, 6], [3, 6, 9, 9, 9], [9, 7, 6, 8, 7], [9, 6, 3, 5, 6], [9, 1, 8, 5, 6]], [[2, 4, 2, 7, 3], [8, 9, 8, 7, 1], [1, 6, 1, 8, 4], [9, 9, 8, 8, 2], [5, 5, 7, 9, 5]], [[6, 4, 3, 1, 2], [6, 4, 4, 7, 6], [7, 7, 6, 1, 3], [8, 7, 1, 4, 7], [4, 7, 1, 1, 2]], [[1, 7, 7, 5, 3], [7, 8, 4, 1, 1], [8, 5, 7, 5, 3], [6, 9, 1, 9, 6], [5, 9, 7, 3, 1]], [[6, 3, 7, 1, 5], [1, 9, 4, 8, 2], [9, 6, 5, 9, 5], [2, 9, 4, 4, 6], [8, 3, 6, 7, 4]]], [[[2, 4, 7, 7, 8], [4, 2, 9, 4, 8], [5, 4, 2, 1, 3], [1, 6, 8, 1, 1], [4, 7, 4, 9, 5]], [[4, 9, 1, 3, 7], [3, 3, 7, 6, 4], [4, 6, 7, 4, 5], [7, 3, 2, 7, 6], [5, 5, 7, 9, 3]], [[7, 6, 7, 4, 1], [8, 3, 4, 7, 3], [1, 9, 9, 2, 4], [2, 7, 2, 8, 1], [5, 1, 4, 8, 8]], [[3, 5, 4, 8, 2], [1, 2, 7, 4, 5], [1, 7, 2, 2, 9], [8, 4, 2, 1, 4], [4, 9, 2, 3, 5]], [[1, 1, 9, 7, 8], [4, 8, 1, 7, 5], [3, 5, 2, 2, 7], [8, 6, 3, 2, 1], [6, 9, 9, 1, 3]]], [[[2, 8, 5, 5, 6], [6, 3, 4, 6, 4], [2, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 6, 1, 1, 2], [6, 4, 9, 8, 5]], [[8, 4, 7, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4, 8, 7], [7, 8, 3, 6, 8], [2, 2, 4, 7, 2], [2, 3, 6, 4, 4]], [[5, 2, 8, 4, 8], [6, 7, 2, 8, 7], [8, 2, 1, 9, 2], [2, 1, 1, 7, 2], [9, 6, 1, 5, 2]], [[3, 2, 9, 2, 2], [9, 4, 5, 1, 2], [9, 1, 6, 3, 7], [8, 8, 7, 1, 8], [3, 4, 8, 9, 6]], [[8, 6, 1, 6, 9], [1, 9, 6, 9, 4], [6, 6, 6, 9, 6], [2, 5, 3, 6, 5], [6, 6, 9, 5, 7]]], [[[2, 4, 3, 6, 1], [6, 8, 2, 8, 8], [5, 2, 9, 7, 7], [1, 3, 5, 6, 2], [5, 3, 5, 7, 9]], [[5, 3, 8, 8, 5], [2, 7, 5, 3, 7], [2, 5, 1, 6, 6], [5, 7, 1, 4, 2], [5, 1, 4, 5, 2]], [[1, 6, 2, 5, 3], [3, 8, 1, 9, 4], [3, 9, 6, 7, 1], [8, 5, 3, 7, 1], [3, 8, 8, 1, 4]], [[3, 1, 2, 1, 9], [5, 7, 1, 4, 2], [1, 8, 5, 7, 3], [2, 5, 8, 2, 1], [9, 9, 6, 9, 7]], [[4, 8, 3, 5, 6], [5, 6, 4, 2, 3], [2, 5, 3, 1, 6], [2, 9, 4, 9, 4], [4, 6, 8, 2, 2]]]] ->
[[[[1, 8, 1, 7, 8], [2, 6, 6, 2, 8], [9, 4, 2, 3, 3], [1, 9, 5, 8, 5], [6, 3, 9, 2, 2]], [[8, 2, 5, 5, 3], [3, 3, 8, 6, 6], [3, 3, 5, 6, 6], [4, 2, 5, 3, 6], [2, 2, 5, 5, 4]], [[4, 4, 1, 9, 7], [4, 3, 4, 3, 8], [3, 7, 1, 7, 7], [1, 2, 7, 5, 6], [5, 6, 5, 4, 6]], [[7, 8, 9, 7, 2], [9, 4, 9, 9, 2], [3, 1, 9, 2, 9], [3, 5, 8, 4, 7], [3, 3, 5, 9, 9]], [[5, 6, 2, 4, 3], [2, 9, 6, 6, 1], [6, 8, 2, 9, 7], [5, 2, 1, 8, 4], [7, 7, 9, 6, 1]]], [[[2, 2, 8, 1, 6], [3, 6, 9, 9, 9], [9, 7, 6, 8, 7], [9, 6, 3, 5, 6], [9, 1, 8, 5, 6]], [[2, 4, 2, 7, 3], [8, 9, 8, 7, 1], [1, 6, 1, 8, 4], [9, 9, 8, 8, 2], [5, 5, 7, 9, 5]], [[6, 4, 3, 1, 2], [6, 4, 4, 7, 6], [7, 7, 6, 1, 3], [8, 7, 1, 4, 7], [4, 7, 1, 1, 2]], [[1, 7, 7, 5, 3], [7, 8, 4, 1, 1], [8, 5, 7, 5, 3], [6, 9, 1, 9, 6], [5, 9, 7, 3, 1]], [[6, 3, 7, 1, 5], [1, 9, 4, 8, 2], [9, 6, 5, 9, 5], [2, 9, 4, 4, 6], [8, 3, 6, 7, 4]]], [[[2, 4, 7, 7, 8], [4, 2, 9, 4, 8], [5, 4, 2, 1, 3], [1, 6, 8, 1, 1], [4, 7, 4, 9, 5]], [[4, 9, 1, 3, 7], [3, 3, 7, 6, 4], [4, 6, 7, 4, 5], [7, 3, 2, 7, 6], [5, 5, 7, 9, 3]], [[7, 6, 7, 4, 1], [8, 3, 4, 7, 3], [1, 9, 9, 2, 4], [2, 7, 2, 8, 1], [5, 1, 4, 8, 8]], [[3, 5, 4, 8, 2], [1, 2, 7, 4, 5], [1, 7, 2, 2, 9], [8, 4, 2, 1, 4], [4, 9, 2, 3, 5]], [[1, 1, 9, 7, 8], [4, 8, 1, 7, 5], [3, 5, 2, 2, 7], [8, 6, 3, 2, 1], [6, 9, 9, 1, 3]]], [[[2, 8, 5, 5, 6], [6, 3, 4, 6, 4], [2, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 6, 1, 1, 2], [6, 4, 9, 8, 5]], [[8, 4, 7, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4, 8, 7], [7, 8, 3, 6, 8], [2, 2, 4, 7, 2], [2, 3, 6, 4, 4]], [[5, 2, 8, 4, 8], [6, 7, 2, 8, 7], [8, 2, 1, 9, 2], [2, 1, 1, 7, 2], [9, 6, 1, 5, 2]], [[3, 2, 9, 2, 2], [9, 4, 5, 1, 2], [9, 1, 6, 3, 7], [8, 8, 7, 1, 8], [3, 4, 8, 9, 6]], [[8, 6, 1, 6, 9], [1, 9, 6, 9, 4], [6, 6, 6, 9, 6], [2, 5, 3, 6, 5], [6, 6, 9, 5, 7]]], [[[2, 4, 3, 6, 1], [6, 8, 2, 8, 8], [5, 2, 9, 7, 7], [1, 3, 5, 6, 2], [5, 3, 5, 7, 9]], [[5, 3, 8, 8, 5], [2, 7, 5, 3, 7], [2, 5, 1, 6, 6], [5, 7, 1, 4, 2], [5, 1, 4, 5, 2]], [[1, 6, 2, 5, 3], [3, 8, 1, 9, 4], [3, 9, 6, 7, 1], [8, 5, 3, 7, 1], [3, 8, 8, 1, 4]], [[3, 1, 2, 1, 9], [5, 7, 1, 4, 2], [1, 8, 5, 7, 3], [2, 5, 8, 2, 1], [9, 9, 6, 9, 7]], [[4, 8, 3, 5, 6], [5, 6, 4, 2, 3], [2, 5, 3, 1, 6], [2, 9, 4, 9, 4], [4, 6, 8, 2, 2]]]]
[[[[9, 8, 7], [6, 1, 8], [9, 8, 8]], [[4, 4, 7], [7, 6, 1], [7, 1, 4]], [[8, 4, 1], [5, 7, 5], [9, 1, 9]]], [[[3, 7, 6], [6, 7, 4], [3, 2, 7]], [[3, 4, 7], [9, 9, 2], [7, 2, 8]], [[2, 7, 4], [7, 2, 2], [4, 2, 1]]], [[[5, 4, 8], [8, 3, 6], [2, 4, 7]], [[7, 2, 8], [2, 1, 9], [1, 1, 7]], [[4, 5, 1], [1, 6, 3], [8, 7, 1]]]]
[[[[9]]]]
```

Comment: Can we assume anything about the inputs, such as positive, non-zero, etc.? (re. suggested edit)

Comment: Can we output a final empty list if the input has even length?

Comment: @att Sure, that's fine

Comment: "_You may output a trailing empty list on testcases with even size._" Why only with even size test cases?.. Can I always output a trailing empty list, even with odd size test cases?

Comment: Can we skip outputting the initial array, and only output subsequent steps?

Comment: @SurculoseSputum Sure, that's fine.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I don't see how having it on odd testcases could help, but sure, you can have that.

Answer (score 8):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>47</s> 44 bytes

```
#//.l_:>(Print@l;#0/@#[[2;;-2]]~Check~#&@l)&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VhNayNHEL3rVwg5LAnIcbqnPyPWCJI9BHJI4twGEYzQxiJay9haWNjs/nVnuuvjdW/2nBAiMHimp6ar6tWr1zV6c3u62725Pe23t8@vXz5fXF19ffjt2@svf3rc35/Wh9XFN1fri3G0q9Wl3Ww@fne32/7x8eLF@vDVi@ef3@53p/X3x3H2fr88fpi/nN@cptd@/2X3cLjd7sbFuLi8Xvy4fzqNi836sL/frWb7yerX46t3D4@7p6f98X69X82On67RNjcPh/1pPC4Xs8VmNXu1vTsW4xrYOC28bu7o/9X6qAvL98XfknZ69e70eLs9jV/cbB/3D6cf7h/enujJtPlsCnK1Wi7ml9ezxZ/l35yWNh82z@M4uuU8LOdxs5yPpl6mcjks59Of25TrMS/nltcn61zWp8tQTTKZTFcRJtNdKJflrendzWZT3f5j3oqnXP6Xi@lNj31SNZoWTLnL9W3DG5i6bVQ3qT6NZU@KIGAfT9FPFuza1Gf8JgVezPlNchQ52cCRTnexBpNKBOIzVAAM21Lsnr2E6mjAPgRKwfd/kysnKu6S0mbAymRE1R9L9JJ0qt4yo2GVcrGaJMbFcAiCgFAu8C6Zsyf22WJNNvwkca4WRLea89C5ih1qlkwIfCPJsLWt8ITGle/Ayah41MIEMCHCJKhJgYBdubqhhXVBkXyVhYY3jjeNDInAn@HBcOodyhRyxC7S@@UF8SW3GoZ49Rp0w@kI@kRmSzURyFUgImqrrhLfKjMt2iQoPsIGU9cH7gev1SIU5FUP4nNWDCERPyNoz2ZZ84pcPFpv6oK8Bm4f2qUpqaN6VV@UjPt7KXKNiPEx4NUAE6/VsoAwoYWNoKOuGpZHxie1Wk1d7LCe@LJ2ejXxEJ7c1ZwOBcjbuZnPzXxu5v96M1MnW7quN4YAxlRHp3/AJJgrKhZloxGECuGbAbEaWeUWNVrTXAw6h0ULHgtOXmmGSt3DaSs6mYEiWOkACE1SPGJBNSJ3vY5Uvr4VWsbkDj6arTIvDOJVdG8QBByopmNU1noQjg7zWxZ4G12yyMdTI9LODT35FaYLIdOoySBDY4YsRxkAhZNBEecFI0NqaFXMdgTMtAXHa2Q0lPCyWAixqVyxpWWQAhmMuFTI2PVgM3QmqaJDnWnBKMV0jBaKRamHgfD5zoIwokIKFwipQVs6yDTeCBbRIYEc4dOBOUtKAQ0a6jauKZqTkBMInyHhXvA36LQgdTaAwbXoOslp6IgYcWg5DYXjpXwt8G@LNrRyHKGfSTotdjIgJxPBEJWYvK0R5JIKr@/A1PZ0gJt2sZ0qW8ifE6@DgmBUFICtyppHv1robJKGsOjFrFg2RUuiQQFa14wEVrpKThH9fOrpnlkvRR6d5CnOFZcIMg/4ULeiJKJRVh47lUcv8AujQlOSiMnNQNishBo7dpv2aB6EqLaTR48UCbUAEiaVDeiyE5XtvkENpi6jn7P45UE/hwOGN0rbd1/LNNa0nTZ8RmYTOs0KXyIOSY8ZxHdlFXQH0ToPwntkbQWUgMZSHbNdS/hWx4Iefc3MAxgGwSV2wjZgQeMy7aBttNifjUXlP@J48oKUgbqHdrhywsv@OOUJoauRQdH0PG0EKcm8gG@M8zByHkbOw8h5GDkPI@dh5DyMnIeRf2UYqZNIBksDeJNb9XA4ECKqG9u0ExTLo/tZ9Ztf6iL6OQJmq3kOcNWMAdxMelxGnNLSG6xV4sqjGVM32rj2xzOLJjdoBtOi7rsjuD0lgWC5@gs)

Prints the steps, one per line. Includes a final empty list if the input has even length

```
#                                           starting from input,
 //.                                        until a fixed point is reached:
    l_:>(Print@l;                         )   output current value
                 #0/@#[[2;;-2]]        &@l    recursively take its middle on every level
                               ~Check~#         or unchanged if length<2
                                                (this also handles recursion base case)
```

---

**43 bytes**, non-competing

```
{#}//.l_:>{#0/@#[[2;;-2]]~Check~#&@@l}⋃l&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VhNayNHEL3rVwg57EmO0z39GWEjSPYQyCGJcxuGYIQ2FtFaxtbCguO95Jh/mT/inen6eN2bPSeECAzu6anuqn716nWN3t4cb7dvb467zc3Lm8uXp7Pni4sv9798ffV09tXF@qzv7Wp1bofhwze3281vH85erdf757/@/GP/6uXHd7vtcf3toZ897ZaH5/nl/Pr4sLv79aft/f5ms@0X/eL8avH97vHYL4b1fne3Xc12o9XPh9fv7x@2j4@7w916t5odPp2jba7v97tjf1guZothNXu9uT1Mxj@Mr479wIOL9RtMjsP55eX8MKjVbPk0uV3Shq/fHx9uNsf@i@vNw@7@@N3d/bsjvRl9zMZYV6vlYn5@NVv8Pv2b09TwPLz0fe@W87Ccx2E5700ZpmnYLefjnxumcZ@Xc8vzo3We5sdhKCaZTMZRhMn4FKbhtGpcOwxDcfuPeZs85en/NBhXeuyTitE4YaanXFYb3sCUbaO6SeVtnPakCAL28RT9aMGuTXnHKynwyZxXkqPIhw0c6fgUSzBpikB8hgKAYVuK3bOXUBx12IdAmfD935yVDyruktKmw8xoRNnvp@jl0Kl4y4yGVcrFYpIYF8MhCAJCucC7ZD49sc9O1mTDbxKf1YLoVs/cNa5ig5olEwLfyGHY2hZ4QuXKN@BkZDxqYgKYEGES1GSCgF25sqGF9YQi@ZomKt443jQyJAJ/hgfDR29QppAjdpHanxaIL3nUMMSr16ArTkfQJzJbiolArgIRkVt1lfhRmWlRJkHxETaYMt9xPXjNFqEgSz2Iz6diCIn4GUF7Nst6rsjJo/kqLzhXx@VDu1QpdZSv4osO4/6eilwiYnwMeNXBxGu2LCBMKGEj6KiriuWR8Um1VlMVO8wnHpZKLyYewpObnNOlAHk7FfOpmE/F/F8vZqpkS@PyYAhgdHV0@wd0grmgYpE2akEoEb5qEIuRVW5RoVXFxaBzWDThMeFkSdVU6h5OS9FJDxTBSgdAqJPiFguqEbnqtaXyZVWoGZMb@Ki3yjzRiVfRvU4QcKCatlFZ80E4OvRvWeCtdMniPJ4KkXau6MlLmC6ETKUmnTSNGbIcpQEUTgZFnCeMNKmhVjHbEDDTFhyvkdZQwstiIcSmdMWalkESZNDiUiJjU4NV05kkiw55pgmjFNM2WigWJR8GwucbC8KIEilcIKQ6Lekg3XglWESHBHKETxvmLEcKKNBQtnFV0pyEnED4DAn3gr9BpQXJswEMrkbXyZm6hogRl5bTUDheOq8F/nXSulqOI/QzSaXFRgbkZiIYohKTtzWCXFLh9Q2YWp4OcNMutlFlC/lz4rVTEIyKArBVWfOoVwudTVIQFrWYFcsqaUk0KEDrqpbASlXJLaKfTy3dM@ulyKOTc4pzxSWCzB0@1K0oiWiUlddO5dEL/MKoUKUkonMzEDYrocaG3aa@mjshqm3k0eOIhFoACZPKBnTZico236AGXZfRz1n88qCfwwHNGx3bN1/L1NbUldZ9RmYTKs0KXyIuSY8exDdpFXQ70ToPwnuc2gooAYWlOmabkvC1jgW9@qqeBzB0gktshK3DhMZl6kbbaLI/G4vKf8T15AUpA3UPdXPlhJftdcodQpMjg6TpfVoJUpJ@Ad8Yp2bk1IycmpFTM3JqRk7NyKkZOTUj/0ozUjqRDJYG8CbX6uFwIURkN9bHTlAsj@pn1a9@qYuo5wiYrZ6zg6uqDeBi0usy4paW2mCtElcexZia1sbVP55ZFLlBMZgadd9cwfUtCQSn0Uc)

Returns the lists in reverse order. I don't expect this is allowed, but it's an interesting variation.

Comment: Why not print to stdout instead of returning the result, so that you can `Echo` each step?

Comment: @alephalpha Besides my not liking to use `Echo`, no particular reason.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 17 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{h↓⍵↓⍨-h←×⍴⎕←⍵}⍣≡
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=q8541Db5Ue9WMLlCF8ibcHj6o94tj/qmAplAidpHvYsfdS4EAA&f=bVY7rlUxDNzK6R5I9xX5OtkCBRSUV7dlE4gOPYHQQ1Ag0SIaNsAGWMpZCefEHk8CT7pFbo4T2@PxxG/3z9/2hy939/f3d/un92@2Z/vD1/3x5/7xx/P9w/fj64vXr15u@@Pvd39@bXfX6zVftnrZ5HbZrmEs27lMl@345du5vvbLFm3/sO7n/rGsw6SrybESmhz/6rk8Tx1nb7fb3fB1HCm8oI2vx0Y4//VxLNjJMO4Tv7@Nr3Jepq4r7yka9mFhPsP4Zic14tPcTqojsSyrhXj8kxFMOyOAzzoyD2arsRfzUoejxHsUDUv1eoaFbNq4plua0YGVYdIs4WB3IzUAW@2WbmkpxvG0Vhv70iyJyHJGTyYtrmSBI6qJohpsv5l1HHnXyVVZsu4spTjilSUWmlQ3OSEwV3lcGGndbvB1bkyEyHapGCTgZqeHYKkvKGvIwlvA8PMAfOGvhwGvxYOeyCrkhRgNhgkg9zYQ1tZdNfvrlIvkf3V8wIYw9pMRvXi1FAUcLWS0ZWUQKqM7gy5m1j0vseLp/lQX5pWsL/SWqaRZ6zV8aTL5/1L0EZHhE8irRJPi1YqEsLE3A9BxVxPLxfBpsyJpe2buN1uOFh4mhYrSl5qr9LGXg6JKjdP2r9TFPqCIrJVqkKJfJrkcRtEJpd01dZQhbbHoRuFGxpFJYv2O7P2XIYJCKmaioFJqGkupEGt119QyTtWZJn3BTMW120aCV4hdAgKZ/HId7V4ExTFTwDvgncQoMp@i3ac3T5y0I8YRRWaSkIRXo1OLBS8AiFgdcdsIeKXqLF1xYV3XKyzegLcB4XVYgM1aLpm5WFGgwDdOCylL402vTkMVM@usG8Ep5u8oKCaoR6DalcVCMdJCgguKVPI@rniOJ5VSOjSSo/77YnakVNmVdVyTp6JlhNxI@E7dLsA/sNMq6hwIQ57RzcgpLUQUvlTZQ7F4Nd9I/OeipVmDhaLZ0GmyyACeI4VBnJh2bQByzdW2LGB6e2bCrbfERYojNS/Da3IQgosCsXVZK@zXSHFtaIjIXuyO5VS0Bg2q1LppDojoKjwdPj@tdO@ml5DHjDzh3HERkjlxbI1QEmhUxOfs8lgAPxhVp5IIx7VAYYsIVRZ2h/k9TiBqXOSxMEVFrZKEzWWDupyhsssQGjhqBZ9nOYf7PFw5sWnaZRmXdZaZOy09IbONnRbBF@HLWDh4lKWsQDdB6woJX5h1BCiVjeU6FpeWKLOOVX/6pkGHMCTgIouwJW54XGGeroMX@8lYXP6Fz1MBUoHqXueJKoOX63NqE8JSo8Ci@Xs6CVLDvHDMIn8B&i=AwA&r=tio&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

A dfn submission which prints each iteration. Input is a multidimensional array.

-14 from ovs.

Comment: If you pass a vector left argument to `↓`, you can drop along multiple axes: `{h↓⍵↓⍨-h←×⍴⎕←⍵}⍣≡`

Comment: I suppose axis specification never really is golfy

Answer (score 5):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-xp`, <s>25</s> <s>24</s> 22 bytes

```lisp
W@<P@ggM:{0*a?fM@<Saa}
```

Takes the input array as a command line argument; outputs each step on a separate line. Gives an empty list at the end for even-size test-cases, as permitted. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY-9CsIwFIXfJaNQMEnz5y3YFygIDg4hQ5YWtwwKBfFJXAQRJ1ffxbfxJA2S5SP3nO8mt0c6ppdnzZxYuD_Pp7Gxn0Pf7fppGjaX9Spux6Hv9jFel2HNfN-eee81KXLUBvKWLJiDHEnipEGcDI4LQMwlWAA16dpRINyDBBquJlsQEiWZXQYkSzK3DbZY2BenJlF2yvIOVUwaLlk7MjvD_2c_)

#### Explanation

This is for a somewhat more straightforward 23-byte version. The 22-byte version works the same way, except that the main program manipulates `g` (the list of all command-line args--in our case, a singleton list) instead of `a` (the first command-line arg). This ends up saving a byte because Pip's function-call syntax is a bit verbose.

```lisp
W@<Paa:({...}a)
                 ; a is 1st cmdline arg (evaluated, thanks to -x flag)
W                ; While...
    a            ;   Current array
   P             ;   Printed (in list format, thanks to -p flag)
 @<              ;   Minus its last element
                 ; ...is truthy (nonempty list), loop:
       (      )  ;   Call
        {...}    ;   This function (see below)
             a   ;   With argument a
     a:          ;   Assign the result back to a

{0*a?fM@<Saa}    ; Recursive function to strip one hypercube layer:
   a             ; The function argument
 0*              ; Times 0 (either 0 for integer a, or list of 0s for list a)
    ?            ; If truthy, the argument is a nonempty list:
         Sa      ;   Argument minus its first element
       @<        ;   Minus its last element
     fM          ;   Map this function recursively to each remaining element
                 ; Else, the argument is an integer:
           a     ;   Return it unchanged
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 57 bytes

```ruby
f=->x{x*0==0?x:x[1..-2].map(&f)}
g=->h{p h
h[2]&&g[f[h]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVfdThZBDL3nKb5wQQA/CfM/Y4I@yLoXaAKYqCFGE4zh2XF32tMzo96YcLE7X3fanp6elm8/Pvx8ebm7ef326dfT5fXNzfW7pzdPi7u6eu3Xqy@3j@dndxfPJ/ebwcOvx8PDycPi17Oz@@VueVjX55fHb5@@fj/cX328/fz5fFmWeDzk46Gsx8Pi@mPdH8PxsP3FdX9e2vHg9Xyzbvv59pi7SROT7anQZHvL@@P@1fbtuq4XJyfi@PT919NXp4fL00t3/Wp72V7xE2Park50VPst24Hb31q/3qkH1/0Wi6P2X8vuVELMvCdJepuFxub6b/qlZLab65fiqCgaWVPZ3koPpu4RwGfuCDm1ldiTesndUeA9gtp/QrLs4SPr2t01hcNboUo3qQqM0xgAAQqV9Zam6UvN/G4tNvpL1WQ96eEt6TC5KhNsXkwEfafnVa19xycPrtKETmPJi1UmkwqFJtlMdgjUVewXelrXFb72g4E4US8tCgm43ujBaeoTyhJy4S3omP0D@MKrhQGvyYIeSF3In6J06SaA3NqqsLbmquqrUdOzT7LhAza4fh60IZJVS1DAp4nM16wUQmF@Y9BJzZrlVbR4cj7UhXkF7R@5ZShplHp1X5JM/LsUrUek@DjyKtAkWbU8IazsYQd0zNXA8qL41FHhpI0jz6s@9lbvJonK06aai5RKz/9f1zvBn@oqgpKpyK2D5llVUTWpUxqEuht5o5704dB7WhONWg4SDyI@GcTd7ojWqRGyWkjaSLxEnFW1KSpFRcFUOvWv8kioNqErct30IMArZDEAgUgmmjI3K5fgGDkSGuAdZMsznyR9KjcP7NVPlE2CzCA2AXOoUbULZgoomw1xPXCYe3kUOT/xs8kVGq/DtEF4DRbgvZSrjKzNKJDj1JRClqlFhzlWUcXIOsuBM4rZZAbFCurhqItpshCMpJDggiAVrOMzBvygZ0KHSnLkP2dwQ0qZ/Zv7NXEoWkTIlYRvVPgE/B07LaPOjjDEEd2InMJExMKZFi0UjVfy9cR/LFoY1bpQXis6rUwygMElMBQjpl7rgFw1XU4TmNaekXDLLX4SbU91jPAaDARnokBsTdYS@9VThisawrMXm2E5FK1CgzK1btgYPLoKQ8Y2spnuTfUS8hiRJ5wbLoVkDlyYPZQEGuXxczR5TIAfjMpDSQoXO0dh8wi1TOx24@QOIKqf5DExRUEtk4TVZIO6HKGy01rruJQ525D5H4Bt2Jm7naSdpgVctp6x08I/ZLay0zz4UjhDE1eUNJUV6AZoXSLhE7P2ACWzsUzH/NQSadSxbKNvWIkIQwAuZRK2wAOLy417uLNi/zMWk//C8ZSAlKO653H3iuDlPE51Q5hq5Fg0m6eDIFXsC9vW8vIb)

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 18 bytes

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
{⍵(⊢↓↓⍨∘-)×⍴⎕←⍵}⍣≡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVa7qmVFEM39ipONwpmgn9Udm6iBgtfscIIBGZMBTUWMhIsOnEER0VRNDAQT/QH9k/0j1727atXq1qtwuezdp3Y9Vq1aXc8@efH0w0@fvfj4o4eHz7bbH69vL3/a7r89/m6/bF/@8PSNv77fbr9vr77b7r/ef/98u/28ffXjw/Px@mp7@cV2@3U3@PO3tN1/s5vdvf/m/v@Dt96@e3h@Oo6G/X70zt177z65XC75fKrnk1zPp0sYj@14TOfT/pevx/Oln0/Rznfrfpzvj3WYdDXZn4Qm@1s9Ho@v9m@v1@uT1x6PvjspdNmG/X4Qjrc@HAXzFUYE8Yht/CqHe02m0k/RQnYLyyKM3@xLreEwty81kFjd1ZLe32Qk044MELMOLILZau7FotQRKNGP4vOfxV@ORFFfG467FR4dfBkmzSAIFg3FAvxqXroVqn2Ih7Xa2C/NyopsefTy0hJKFoCimijOwc6bWceBRJ1ClQWHzuaK96Cy6UKT6iYHBBYqD4eR1u2KWMfBRJFsTsUgAX87IwQrfUFZUxZ6wRQcHyAWXj0NRC2e9ERfIVPEiDFMALmPirC3HqrZq5MwciKq4wM2hHGejPrFu6Uo4NNCjltVBqFyvDPpYmbd6xJrnp5PfWFdySZFvUwtzdqvEUuLyf9uRR8ZGT6BvEo0Kd6tSAgbpzUAHQ81sVwMnzarlg5s5nmzxzHUw6RQY/rSc5XH/5vuoDhTGVUiKtW0D3Aiu6c6pf0ok8gOo@gU03mbZsywt@z0oPAg45NJmN1H9onMEEohOTNxUbk1HaZ4iA2/624ZX9WZOH1BUQW420FCVMhfAgKZjHOt7d4WxTFT5DvgneQpsp6i86ieJ5baJ8YaRWYSlYSbpVOdBbcEqFkdcTsIuMnqLGZx4WFXF5ZvwP2B9DoswG9tl8zsrGhQ4D2ojZRlFKebqaGLmX3Wg@AU87sWFBP0I1D/ymKhGGkjwQVFKvlkV1zZk24pHRrJUf95q3aUVDmndbjJU9MyUm4kfKeSF@AfOGkVfQ6EIc/oZtSUFiIK767sqVi@Wm8k/nPT0qzKQhltmDRZZAAXlMIgTkxzG4Bcc/0tC5g@nplwq5e4iHOkCmZETQ5CcFEgti5rhfMaKbcNAxE5i92xnJrWoEGVWjdtBhFThcvEd6yV7t30EvKYUSeCOy5CMicuuxFKAo2K@Dm7PBbAD0bVqSXCBS5Q2CJSlYXdYb6hE4gaF3ksLFFRqyRhc9mgLmeo7LKoBi5fwXdebu@@M1fucFp2WVZq3W7mSUuPyGzjpEXwRXhXFq4iZWkr0E3QukLCF1YdAUrlYLmOxWUkyqxj1a@@afUhDAm4yCJsiQeeV5j37eDNfjQXl3/h9VSAVKC613nHyuDlep3ahrD0KLBpfp9OgtSwL@zbyd8)

`{`…`}⍣≡`  apply lambda until stable

`⎕←⍵` print the argument

`⍴` get its shape

`×` signum of that (gives list with one 1 per dimension)

`⍵(`…`)` apply the following tacit function with the argument as left argument:

…`∘-` negate the right argument (the number of elements to drop, so they'll be dropped from the rear

`↓⍨` drop that many elements from the left argument

`⊢↓` drop right-argument elements from that

Answer (score 4):

## Python + NumPy, 74 bytes --> 64 bytes (@DLosc)

```python
def x(a): 
 if len(a):print(a);x(a[(slice(1,-1),)*len(a.shape)])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVZdb9swDHzvr9BjMngFJFFfHfZLgjwEW4oGaFMjyYDl12e2yCPtoUXQxrR0Io/HU8f77e3zHB@nj/HzcnPnPx/j3R2u7jw@HdzP6c/z4XI53De76ccPrg5u@l2mL/vB7cLgcv8ECbTBUX@K02cOTIunWOob0xzI/V3ri8J@juxqf0j90zfFvqYyuAWSBQhbogTCAoMYlnounECRTbHHomQbeyVcT5FsQ39KAstHpr4rM2zpmbW@LFjNjYsSWI8SmwSYAZJztJ55F8Mm8EhCQuhvmV4vzDFTqCf1J24KzYHSk2qyhXGFGe4byMzIt0kBpceqADNCNBoajklKQ0Cni@TLpFSmVMjMq/QaVlQhitvFKSeGzWiQlzUcIE7RimRkHMxdJOszB7xKTHpsEivoh5dsK3LBCuaIGwktMFOxsyvZqoaSyZ2sxAYBNVkRsIIEtrKIOwwtmkZIuZrgBVuyIfQ/Gt3VKmIAWrJLqCmuhMh8kmzK2JeEqIg@5/@bFnUkdJO3msjE4XVA5BwGFGEKrAdzlWEjJg9k6niS0c0omLS6YAX1NBhSUi14tBLcqq0lm1eGLQKbwYM3cQiXi6ZVeFA2ryNjN2CqiuQboOS13Jv4JeyRUCcOV16KiZlVVM0NyTwq4DWpPSbQD0XlRUtQdVArExQPohbq9kyXNi2Yv6s9JiuRWcsmwqq2Yb5McNmsJGTsa6Yo7gNJ@hkBXAkJZSdbwddRWU9a/MJmq01agF5wS@htBB9btBXsRnhdMsEnqzqAlGyDpT4WViORlj6W9eoTqip6RBJoGMeFsUULaF5etSB@y0Bf5qL2X@x6SmDKm7tnuZ5gN3V1jyRoMKxQol1OanJtZUgV/y/s99vH7@Or@7s5bF/ckzu9uvfjeX4YL6fzbfryY3q121zfT7@OGz9899th@60veb6@HcbjdgKYNz/@AQ)

Thank's @DLosc for removing the return. Nice spot.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice answer.

Comment: By removing `return` and using one space for the indent, you can get this down to 63 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYvRCoMwDEXf/Yo8tiMTnFKnY19S@lC2igWtpTqYX@@SbjAI5OTm3Lhv4xLqw89xSRuE1xx3sCuEWFi40yptSnYXWusGQSG0BkFXGa@MNQJNY5h1h3D55WR3nBOqrHRfhaj9K3QpRm5R1xgjj6cb4C2s7AvwA0wuMMfkw0Zwo48W6@QfTlR4riTKU1bKdbTRSepz9/gA) (I used a smaller test case so the link would fit in the comment.)

Comment: Based on @DLosc 's golfing. This can be 61 bytes `def x(a):len(a)and x(a[(slice(1,-1,print(a)),)*len(a.shape)])`

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 75 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:[x]+(x[2:]and f(q(x)))
q=lambda x:0!=x*0and[*map(q,x[1:-1])]or x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVbLbtwwDLz3K9ybnbpAJFGvBfIlhg8bBIsWaDa7QQ7O12@9Ioe0gwRGENPSiBwOR7l8fvx5O4fb7fT07/j6/HLslsO0zL/6ZfKH@Xh@6U79tV@GYfhxtRWPP5@Wh8f16/Twerz013GZ3OG3m4f57b1bbpf3v@eP/tRP648buzJ26@@8/jGP3eTHLrXHS6COHbW3sD73wLp4jcW2Md4DqX2rbZGf75GptJfYnrYptDWFwS0QLUDYEiTgNxjEsNRy4QSybAotFiTb0CrherJk69tbFFg@MrZdiWFzy6y2Zd5qrlyUwDqUWCXADJCco/XcdzFsBI8kJPj2lel1whwzhXpie@Om0D2QW1JVtjCuMMN9A5kJ@VYpILdYEWBGCEZDxTFRafDodJZ8mZTClAqZaZdexYoiRHG7OOXIsAkNcrKGA8QpWpGMjIO5i2R95oBTiUmPTWIZ/XCSbUEuWMEccSOhBWYqNHYlW9VQNLmTlVghoCorPFaQwBYWcYOhTdMIKRcTvGBLNoT@B6O7WEUMQFt2CTWFnRCZT5JNCfuiEBXQ5/S1aUFHQjc5q4lMHE4HRM5hQBGmwDowVxg2YPJApo4nGd2MgkkrG1ZQT4UhRdWCQyvBrdpatHll2CywCTw4E4dwuWlagQcl8zoydj2mKku@Hkrey72KX8IeCXXicOUlm5hZRcXckMyjPD6T2mME/VBU2rQEVXu1MkFxIGqjbsd0adO8@bvaY7QSmbVkIixqG@bLBJdNSkLCvmqK4j6QpJ8QwJUQUXa0FXwd5f2khW9sttikeegFt4TeRvCxTVvBboDXRRN8tKo9SEk2WOpjfjcScetjSa8@oaqgRySBinHcGFuwgOblVAvitwz0bS5q/9mupwimnLl7kusJdlN290iEBv0OJdjlpCZXd4ZU8P/CPA/D7T8)

-7 bytes + fixed thanks to DLosc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133576/discussion-between-dialfrost-and-dlosc).

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, 53 bytes

```javascript
f=a=>[a,...g(a)+''&&f(b)]
g=a=>b=a.map?.(g).slice(1,-1)??a
```

```js
f=a=>[a,...g(a)+''&&f(b)]
g=a=>b=a.map?.(g).slice(1,-1)??a

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([[[4, 6, 7], [1, 6, 8], [3, 3, 4]], [[9, 2, 8], [4, 9, 4], [6, 3, 9]], [[3, 7, 8], [4, 3, 6], [2, 8, 2]]])))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([[[6, 5, 9, 4], [8, 8, 5, 1], [9, 3, 1, 6], [1, 7, 7, 9]], [[8, 3, 7, 2], [6, 6, 9, 4], [5, 6, 8, 3], [2, 1, 9, 9]], [[4, 9, 6, 9], [6, 9, 3, 7], [3, 6, 8, 2], [7, 5, 8, 6]], [[8, 6, 2, 1], [3, 5, 9, 5], [2, 6, 1, 3], [3, 6, 3, 9]]])))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([[[[[5, 1, 6], [8, 2, 9], [9, 2, 4]], [[7, 1, 8], [1, 1, 5], [6, 9, 4]], [[3, 6, 6], [9, 9, 9], [4, 2, 5]]], [[[9, 9, 8], [7, 2, 7], [1, 2, 6]], [[3, 1, 8], [1, 7, 9], [6, 9, 2]], [[6, 6, 1], [6, 8, 8], [2, 5, 6]]], [[[9, 5, 3], [3, 6, 9], [8, 8, 7]], [[4, 6, 4], [8, 7, 9], [8, 6, 7]], [[2, 4, 1], [4, 5, 2], [8, 7, 8]]]], [[[[8, 1, 6], [1, 4, 4], [7, 6, 6]], [[9, 9, 9], [8, 1, 7], [9, 2, 4]], [[9, 5, 7], [1, 4, 8], [3, 8, 1]]], [[[3, 8, 1], [8, 7, 6], [1, 5, 7]], [[8, 5, 1], [7, 2, 1], [7, 1, 3]], [[1, 2, 6], [4, 3, 7], [1, 1, 1]]], [[[8, 1, 1], [7, 5, 2], [9, 3, 6]], [[2, 1, 5], [1, 3, 3], [5, 5, 2]], [[7, 6, 2], [9, 5, 7], [3, 8, 1]]]], [[[[5, 8, 9], [7, 2, 5], [3, 9, 7]], [[7, 8, 7], [3, 4, 1], [4, 1, 3]], [[3, 8, 6], [7, 7, 9], [8, 4, 8]]], [[[7, 5, 4], [8, 1, 7], [9, 9, 1]], [[1, 1, 8], [2, 3, 7], [9, 5, 4]], [[2, 2, 6], [8, 8, 2], [1, 3, 6]]], [[[7, 2, 7], [1, 7, 3], [8, 3, 9]], [[6, 1, 4], [8, 3, 8], [8, 9, 5]], [[5, 7, 2], [9, 7, 6], [1, 3, 4]]]]])))
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([[[[1, 8, 1, 7, 8], [2, 6, 6, 2, 8], [9, 4, 2, 3, 3], [1, 9, 5, 8, 5], [6, 3, 9, 2, 2]], [[8, 2, 5, 5, 3], [3, 3, 8, 6, 6], [3, 3, 5, 6, 6], [4, 2, 5, 3, 6], [2, 2, 5, 5, 4]], [[4, 4, 1, 9, 7], [4, 3, 4, 3, 8], [3, 7, 1, 7, 7], [1, 2, 7, 5, 6], [5, 6, 5, 4, 6]], [[7, 8, 9, 7, 2], [9, 4, 9, 9, 2], [3, 1, 9, 2, 9], [3, 5, 8, 4, 7], [3, 3, 5, 9, 9]], [[5, 6, 2, 4, 3], [2, 9, 6, 6, 1], [6, 8, 2, 9, 7], [5, 2, 1, 8, 4], [7, 7, 9, 6, 1]]], [[[2, 2, 8, 1, 6], [3, 6, 9, 9, 9], [9, 7, 6, 8, 7], [9, 6, 3, 5, 6], [9, 1, 8, 5, 6]], [[2, 4, 2, 7, 3], [8, 9, 8, 7, 1], [1, 6, 1, 8, 4], [9, 9, 8, 8, 2], [5, 5, 7, 9, 5]], [[6, 4, 3, 1, 2], [6, 4, 4, 7, 6], [7, 7, 6, 1, 3], [8, 7, 1, 4, 7], [4, 7, 1, 1, 2]], [[1, 7, 7, 5, 3], [7, 8, 4, 1, 1], [8, 5, 7, 5, 3], [6, 9, 1, 9, 6], [5, 9, 7, 3, 1]], [[6, 3, 7, 1, 5], [1, 9, 4, 8, 2], [9, 6, 5, 9, 5], [2, 9, 4, 4, 6], [8, 3, 6, 7, 4]]], [[[2, 4, 7, 7, 8], [4, 2, 9, 4, 8], [5, 4, 2, 1, 3], [1, 6, 8, 1, 1], [4, 7, 4, 9, 5]], [[4, 9, 1, 3, 7], [3, 3, 7, 6, 4], [4, 6, 7, 4, 5], [7, 3, 2, 7, 6], [5, 5, 7, 9, 3]], [[7, 6, 7, 4, 1], [8, 3, 4, 7, 3], [1, 9, 9, 2, 4], [2, 7, 2, 8, 1], [5, 1, 4, 8, 8]], [[3, 5, 4, 8, 2], [1, 2, 7, 4, 5], [1, 7, 2, 2, 9], [8, 4, 2, 1, 4], [4, 9, 2, 3, 5]], [[1, 1, 9, 7, 8], [4, 8, 1, 7, 5], [3, 5, 2, 2, 7], [8, 6, 3, 2, 1], [6, 9, 9, 1, 3]]], [[[2, 8, 5, 5, 6], [6, 3, 4, 6, 4], [2, 3, 5, 7, 9], [2, 6, 1, 1, 2], [6, 4, 9, 8, 5]], [[8, 4, 7, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4, 8, 7], [7, 8, 3, 6, 8], [2, 2, 4, 7, 2], [2, 3, 6, 4, 4]], [[5, 2, 8, 4, 8], [6, 7, 2, 8, 7], [8, 2, 1, 9, 2], [2, 1, 1, 7, 2], [9, 6, 1, 5, 2]], [[3, 2, 9, 2, 2], [9, 4, 5, 1, 2], [9, 1, 6, 3, 7], [8, 8, 7, 1, 8], [3, 4, 8, 9, 6]], [[8, 6, 1, 6, 9], [1, 9, 6, 9, 4], [6, 6, 6, 9, 6], [2, 5, 3, 6, 5], [6, 6, 9, 5, 7]]], [[[2, 4, 3, 6, 1], [6, 8, 2, 8, 8], [5, 2, 9, 7, 7], [1, 3, 5, 6, 2], [5, 3, 5, 7, 9]], [[5, 3, 8, 8, 5], [2, 7, 5, 3, 7], [2, 5, 1, 6, 6], [5, 7, 1, 4, 2], [5, 1, 4, 5, 2]], [[1, 6, 2, 5, 3], [3, 8, 1, 9, 4], [3, 9, 6, 7, 1], [8, 5, 3, 7, 1], [3, 8, 8, 1, 4]], [[3, 1, 2, 1, 9], [5, 7, 1, 4, 2], [1, 8, 5, 7, 3], [2, 5, 8, 2, 1], [9, 9, 6, 9, 7]], [[4, 8, 3, 5, 6], [5, 6, 4, 2, 3], [2, 5, 3, 1, 6], [2, 9, 4, 9, 4], [4, 6, 8, 2, 2]]]])))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>34</s> 32 bytes

```
#~ArrayPad~-1&~FixedPointList~#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVZNaxtBDL3nV5im5LRlme@ZQ6E9tFDoITS9tT2YxG4XGic4W0gJ9l9P15KetBtqluCVZzRPT09vcrsef21u1@NwvX7evn0@P77f79d/L9c3xzfu4vhxeNzcXN4Nu/Hz8DAezy@eX19d74f78dPu/s94Ne6H3c@@/3r34fF@v3l4GO52fb/t@y/Ddvt78@28e/V99@rHRd9fTgvH/t20/2n6uG5Vu9X0t0xfDt3qyXerTI@XQOtWkd7C9JwC0@Iplmjj2Wr6pFM004JGK/3hFHmq9JLooZ2B1lQ@wQKpozQajdgXJOBniSLnjoSKoRTZRFkC/RAEfKDCuLwi4D29JcmdCE2iXZQg8wGFgDZa642HxjVKboeKmwSIFa4myomokbZy7gSCoxDj6Vfm3QmblIUpRI2J3rhl8RQoBK/JPk4ubHFXpSKGkQG/ST2FYlWyc5pg1DScxV3uQI2HIorAZ6Iqcy0s5wVQOpd5qRT1Uk9CBYlzZ7TPyRoORFpm1RSAdwaBGx1NDxxwqkeRgeCAKLnRLCYnqRIkEgRCQ6@hmSZoCoNV8Cq4ZKMSreIGtTVZ4QVNQ5lZIHC/Cgle@xqlAhZ3hDgg3SrgInQSrBnVCuQscU57lBIZTFhIl4mOsjNjcxLyAqSQraWgpp0gYJx0p7MSo4nI6XDJYaCmqJ7lAAdKK@cOmF@wrEMe5w7F7fc2r3XGFMprsLqkmnGm3Rnz6prJRp9zF8mdwY0zEZ1Jr6k31tcKd8tmpdFo9xhLzEAzp3YvR4UnMakFR5QNGMSVzmKxGWDJVXPcaO7n8XNUC0afPQaoygHaMDDh1SkllQN5nMAmwzGP2ldvV4pacLKKmcn8QrZVvchugQg7z0pMls3MprPmcKuiVJMRwFWUQEWyFW0m@@W8hoWpV1BTzc/b4nYKM7s1m9T22w3CN2lVH4FjSSpvNufswk0zm/SLcUpzm8y4cPlKFQ4r2hgl0DDUM98MFlCElMWpcMTdOdt/UTmMRLELMplmIebWWbuKGlldXGIJqvXzarSNzvqqF/zM6ir@nzkc/gE)

- `ArrayPad[array,-1]` negatively pad 1 element on every side regardless the dimension of `array`.
- `FixedPointList[f, x]` applies function `f` on `x` repeatedly, until a fixed-point of `f` is reached.

The result is collected in a `List`, extra code (`Grid[...]`) is needed for aesthetic view.

Example for Notebook environment:

```
{{7, 2, 3, 6, 4}, {2, 4, 9, 9, 8}, {7, 3, 1, 9, 8}, {9, 1, 7, 6, 9}, {4, 3, 4, 8, 5}} //
  #~ArrayPad~-1&~FixedPointList~#& //
 Grid[#,Dividers->{False,Center},Alignment->Left]&
```

Comment: Nice one, I didn't know `ArrayPad` did that. `#//.l_:>ArrayPad[Print@l;l,-1]&` for 31 bytes printing output (or 27 if you're ok with `Echo` instead of `Print`).

Comment: @att Thanks! I'm fine with `Echo`, except `Echo@#~ArrayPad~-1&~FixedPoint~#&` is longer than current version.

Comment: Using `//.` will almost always be shorter than `FixedPoint` for golfing.

Comment: @att Thanks for the tips! I'm not a regular for code golfing. So is it ok to "derive" a language from existing ones just for golfing? Say, a "compact WL" where all the long/full names are replaced with single Unicode symbols.

Comment: This site is pretty liberal with what can be used as a language. [Sledgehammer](https://github.com/tkwa/Sledgehammer) is a golfing language already based on it; using it is more like atomic code golf, doing away with all the syntax.

Comment: You can also check out [this thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/12900/tips-for-golfing-in-mathematica/) for a collection of golfing tips for Mathematica/WL in particular.

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 20 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
×∘≠¨⊸/×∘≢⊸(-∘⊣↓↓)⍟⊒˜
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=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)

`...⍟⊒˜` Iterate 0 to length-1 times, collecting the results:
`×∘≢⊸(-∘⊣↓↓)` Drop the outer face.

`×∘≠¨⊸/` Remove empty arrays from the output.

Calculating the length of the output to avoid the last step is a byte longer:

```
×∘≢⊸(-∘⊣↓↓)⍟(↕·⌈2÷˜≠)
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgw5fiiJjiiaLiirgoLeKImOKKo+KGk+KGkynijZ8o4oaVwrfijIgyw7fLnOKJoCkKCkbCqCA+4o2fKDEty5ziiaEp4oiY4oCiSnPCqCDin6gKIltbWzQsNiw3XSxbMSw2LDhdLFszLDMsNF1dLFtbOSwyLDhdLFs0LDksNF0sWzYsMyw5XV0sW1szLDcsOF0sWzQsMyw2XSxbMiw4LDJdXV0iCiJbW1s2LDUsOSw0XSxbOCw4LDUsMV0sWzksMywxLDZdLFsxLDcsNyw5XV0sW1s4LDMsNywyXSxbNiw2LDksNF0sWzUsNiw4LDNdLFsyLDEsOSw5XV0sW1s0LDksNiw5XSxbNiw5LDMsN10sWzMsNiw4LDJdLFs3LDUsOCw2XV0sW1s4LDYsMiwxXSxbMyw1LDksNV0sWzIsNiwxLDNdLFszLDYsMyw5XV1dIgoiW1tbW1s1LDEsNl0sWzgsMiw5XSxbOSwyLDRdXSxbWzcsMSw4XSxbMSwxLDVdLFs2LDksNF1dLFtbMyw2LDZdLFs5LDksOV0sWzQsMiw1XV1dLFtbWzksOSw4XSxbNywyLDddLFsxLDIsNl1dLFtbMywxLDhdLFsxLDcsOV0sWzYsOSwyXV0sW1s2LDYsMV0sWzYsOCw4XSxbMiw1LDZdXV0sW1tbOSw1LDNdLFszLDYsOV0sWzgsOCw3XV0sW1s0LDYsNF0sWzgsNyw5XSxbOCw2LDddXSxbWzIsNCwxXSxbNCw1LDJdLFs4LDcsOF1dXV0sW1tbWzgsMSw2XSxbMSw0LDRdLFs3LDYsNl1dLFtbOSw5LDldLFs4LDEsN10sWzksMiw0XV0sW1s5LDUsN10sWzEsNCw4XSxbMyw4LDFdXV0sW1tbMyw4LDFdLFs4LDcsNl0sWzEsNSw3XV0sW1s4LDUsMV0sWzcsMiwxXSxbNywxLDNdXSxbWzEsMiw2XSxbNCwzLDddLFsxLDEsMV1dXSxbW1s4LDEsMV0sWzcsNSwyXSxbOSwzLDZdXSxbWzIsMSw1XSxbMSwzLDNdLFs1LDUsMl1dLFtbNyw2LDJdLFs5LDUsN10sWzMsOCwxXV1dXSxbW1tbNSw4LDldLFs3LDIsNV0sWzMsOSw3XV0sW1s3LDgsN10sWzMsNCwxXSxbNCwxLDNdXSxbWzMsOCw2XSxbNyw3LDldLFs4LDQsOF1dXSxbW1s3LDUsNF0sWzgsMSw3XSxbOSw5LDFdXSxbWzEsMSw4XSxbMiwzLDddLFs5LDUsNF1dLFtbMiwyLDZdLFs4LDgsMl0sWzEsMyw2XV1dLFtbWzcsMiw3XSxbMSw3LDNdLFs4LDMsOV1dLFtbNiwxLDRdLFs4LDMsOF0sWzgsOSw1XV0sW1s1LDcsMl0sWzksNyw2XSxbMSwzLDRdXV1dXSIKIltbW1sxLDgsMSw3LDhdLFsyLDYsNiwyLDhdLFs5LDQsMiwzLDNdLFsxLDksNSw4LDVdLFs2LDMsOSwyLDJdXSxbWzgsMiw1LDUsM10sWzMsMyw4LDYsNl0sWzMsMyw1LDYsNl0sWzQsMiw1LDMsNl0sWzIsMiw1LDUsNF1dLFtbNCw0LDEsOSw3XSxbNCwzLDQsMyw4XSxbMyw3LDEsNyw3XSxbMSwyLDcsNSw2XSxbNSw2LDUsNCw2XV0sW1s3LDgsOSw3LDJdLFs5LDQsOSw5LDJdLFszLDEsOSwyLDldLFszLDUsOCw0LDddLFszLDMsNSw5LDldXSxbWzUsNiwyLDQsM10sWzIsOSw2LDYsMV0sWzYsOCwyLDksN10sWzUsMiwxLDgsNF0sWzcsNyw5LDYsMV1dXSxbW1syLDIsOCwxLDZdLFszLDYsOSw5LDldLFs5LDcsNiw4LDddLFs5LDYsMyw1LDZdLFs5LDEsOCw1LDZdXSxbWzIsNCwyLDcsM10sWzgsOSw4LDcsMV0sWzEsNiwxLDgsNF0sWzksOSw4LDgsMl0sWzUsNSw3LDksNV1dLFtbNiw0LDMsMSwyXSxbNiw0LDQsNyw2XSxbNyw3LDYsMSwzXSxbOCw3LDEsNCw3XSxbNCw3LDEsMSwyXV0sW1sxLDcsNyw1LDNdLFs3LDgsNCwxLDFdLFs4LDUsNyw1LDNdLFs2LDksMSw5LDZdLFs1LDksNywzLDFdXSxbWzYsMyw3LDEsNV0sWzEsOSw0LDgsMl0sWzksNiw1LDksNV0sWzIsOSw0LDQsNl0sWzgsMyw2LDcsNF1dXSxbW1syLDQsNyw3LDhdLFs0LDIsOSw0LDhdLFs1LDQsMiwxLDNdLFsxLDYsOCwxLDFdLFs0LDcsNCw5LDVdXSxbWzQsOSwxLDMsN10sWzMsMyw3LDYsNF0sWzQsNiw3LDQsNV0sWzcsMywyLDcsNl0sWzUsNSw3LDksM11dLFtbNyw2LDcsNCwxXSxbOCwzLDQsNywzXSxbMSw5LDksMiw0XSxbMiw3LDIsOCwxXSxbNSwxLDQsOCw4XV0sW1szLDUsNCw4LDJdLFsxLDIsNyw0LDVdLFsxLDcsMiwyLDldLFs4LDQsMiwxLDRdLFs0LDksMiwzLDVdXSxbWzEsMSw5LDcsOF0sWzQsOCwxLDcsNV0sWzMsNSwyLDIsN10sWzgsNiwzLDIsMV0sWzYsOSw5LDEsM11dXSxbW1syLDgsNSw1LDZdLFs2LDMsNCw2LDRdLFsyLDMsNSw3LDldLFsyLDYsMSwxLDJdLFs2LDQsOSw4LDVdXSxbWzgsNCw3LDIsMV0sWzYsNSw0LDgsN10sWzcsOCwzLDYsOF0sWzIsMiw0LDcsMl0sWzIsMyw2LDQsNF1dLFtbNSwyLDgsNCw4XSxbNiw3LDIsOCw3XSxbOCwyLDEsOSwyXSxbMiwxLDEsNywyXSxbOSw2LDEsNSwyXV0sW1szLDIsOSwyLDJdLFs5LDQsNSwxLDJdLFs5LDEsNiwzLDddLFs4LDgsNywxLDhdLFszLDQsOCw5LDZdXSxbWzgsNiwxLDYsOV0sWzEsOSw2LDksNF0sWzYsNiw2LDksNl0sWzIsNSwzLDYsNV0sWzYsNiw5LDUsN11dXSxbW1syLDQsMyw2LDFdLFs2LDgsMiw4LDhdLFs1LDIsOSw3LDddLFsxLDMsNSw2LDJdLFs1LDMsNSw3LDldXSxbWzUsMyw4LDgsNV0sWzIsNyw1LDMsN10sWzIsNSwxLDYsNl0sWzUsNywxLDQsMl0sWzUsMSw0LDUsMl1dLFtbMSw2LDIsNSwzXSxbMyw4LDEsOSw0XSxbMyw5LDYsNywxXSxbOCw1LDMsNywxXSxbMyw4LDgsMSw0XV0sW1szLDEsMiwxLDldLFs1LDcsMSw0LDJdLFsxLDgsNSw3LDNdLFsyLDUsOCwyLDFdLFs5LDksNiw5LDddXSxbWzQsOCwzLDUsNl0sWzUsNiw0LDIsM10sWzIsNSwzLDEsNl0sWzIsOSw0LDksNF0sWzQsNiw4LDIsMl1dXV0iCuKfqQ==)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 12 bytes

```
ẉ&{ċbk↰ᵐ|ℕ}↰
```

Outputs one array per line. Includes an empty array for even-length inputs. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GuTrXqI91J2Y/aNjzcOqHmUcvUWiDz///o6GgzHQVTHQVLHQWTWB2FaAsdBQuwgCGIBxQ1BjJ1FMxAPCBtDkaWsSAuSK0xmG8E4gLNMUOYYwrmgVSAeEZgQyzhOk3AHJByqE6IReYgnjFMJ9hUc7BjLEAugNkJlDWCus8Y5nZTqC1mYIuMEeYYg@2MBQA)

#### Explanation

```
ẉ&{ċbk↰ᵐ|ℕ}↰
ẉ             Write the input to stdout with a trailing newline
 &            And, with the input
  {       }   Apply this predicate to remove one hypercube layer:
   ċ            The input must be a list
    b           Remove the first element
     k          Remove the last element
      ↰ᵐ        Map the current predicate recursively to each remaining element
        |       Or, if that definition fails, try this one:
         ℕ      The input is a nonnegative integer (return it unchanged)
           ↰  After removing a layer, call the outer predicate recursively
              The recursion continues until the predicate fails
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Δ=DdΔ€`}\N>"ε¦¨"×¦.V
```

Will always output a single trailing empty list.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ZVI7TsVADLxK9OoIaZP9FlBRU9KESICgoKKgpuEMT@IGTxS0XCD0OQQXCfHYXq/0Unmd8Yw99uvbw@PL87atx8vrp/X49/F9/353c3VYf5bT8nX4/VxOF7fbNtEX@s71XZz7bsp9N/RdobAg9DPFUwIkU@wQBgrjDq2QcacQloI8WDxYwswY@QOehD9JKAcqVZ5GKgkPSw0MiZByks@CJh2wVKn9OdKDWysyYCZVYDzyXvLJILFCyAKR8iAcDJ1n1aKEWuhQ4WXEWOdqTGF0OnOZW07GkqV7KlAtfdY2VDXUpjMezlzW0JEhgKjlPNdoqq6RyvLkYh2@AB@rP3oNDnkYHgSttxOtVAe0qcTCgESxpoPASp0ryfI43@zF5mLaKCzNSj3vC1o8jD9fRUFH4o@zuxoNEuq2BrOQr2owF2Ij1Vx5En8yQKVes7NuRlHN6CYwJKBULWx2PqKb/fsH) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##XVa9bpQxEOx5iuhqC8m/ayNBGhoa6Gg@TgIEBQ0gJUFKkYZniMQbRBS08ABHn4fgRYJ3drwXyBXx@Wc9Ozuzvk9nb95@eH/3Zffs4@eL80cnu9PL8GD34uJ8fjubX8Pl3e3146fvbq//fP3x@urV8ye725@Hm8P33e9vh5uHL@@uDr9O77Ztk5BCDi2UfdhSKGHMT59jmbOR4zFHMveMOS5zvoQe6n4fTub5Mudlzsf5X/dmXZ9r2zyVMKMxNXqbKwMreUbrjNVwbw9pz4AtVB7oek2IAKBgGq6R@bEwPWighNCNZ6rCCBlBFb7tVAgGX/dlAM7YmZBqnaPGmG3CjlhXHBWR2oyVeQZJGNRtXmewZiCE15wte5krHYAjghhAy77hzAA8ZSEpm7q0HdlPZDURWPZ44okkrGjyETMdO2Y0PcN41YEPUiqkpJFk4UrjiqogAlcFPR3VYsD5bRWi4LwgG6v3YKQI7EcuFIXwjGlk7mFAG9stFrcSxyq@sCCCIuiKsWL6EXK84nWMraiJ0mnMyyoxo4CTih1Wq8a9ldIwfJaximMQR8XqIEIBmzqzGFsIMwSlZxa7BRwGOK6S@cXT0NuQV2QFM1cqGUzMuFOy0bJivKUVQV7dfaayLZzp@D/gW81JmPFiHa51YccAdETTYArrBAX9IuPMgHHq8vZcSaycanApD1zgFh1XjqF697/tL1RmgXXFu02magSYli8EOjfLz7OsstZkeHbWzxJORyActLZWRBzTahQVmRY2kBHueysRU1U96vlVX@yxWmgmyyHwHD0BnqmWgSZS2QMimlxz5yWv4tD9uD2iAdmN6BBUgXImXtMGpiIborIorsHVwBCRmReMI2tmjdVqJmAn0pfV5zUfZdFY15wylduCVadSF4UIR2j32ugAqkZFzn4DzRlvBfd3KmOwU1QwEqm3Fpa7dXfxzAtwZa@nsLcVuwO3K9ZERhZv2d0vdHCH3sT1bT1MsYtVFqfRx9TPcHr1bE2VhSzoieTuT/RiQcxM5NGUzrzNc5UKTfR1h14SdTgsV@etwzmNHiz@kmfL0Z@voy4GX@8NuMQjWx7C@me@5ylYbRKjQln0SgqddWrkR/gWRrou4WZxLUTvuRlVTu7TSoSaXWMtuzmA7i9w9vGZjnzToj3u/I1hPwUa30HFW/0HAl4W11v@x9udeoPL2WOsW5nTFp@WeYYHK5VRiTchi0aNmdOSK6a605r1vvXSEHtGHuKuyxzbXdF/PUTj9787rI8IO1dFTpH9ovmLVVDZY99EN3euInmzvrkc1K2vz7@/).

**Explanation:**

```python
Δ            # Continue looping until the result no longer changes:
 =           #  Print the current multi-dimensional matrix with trailing newline
             #  (without popping)
             #  (which will use the implicit input in the first iteration)
  DdΔ€`}\N>  #  Determine the depth of this multi-dimensional matrix:
  D          #   Duplicate it
   d         #   Transform each inner integer to a 1 (with a >=0 check)
    Δ        #   Inner loop until the result no longer changes:
     €`      #    Flatten one level down
       }\    #   After the inner loop: discard the result
         N>  #   Push the last 1-based index instead (0-based index + 1) 
   "ε¦¨"×    #  Repeat "ε¦¨" that many times as string
         ¦   #  Remove the leading "ε"
          .V #  Evaluate and execute it as 05AB1E code:
    ε        #  Map over each inner list:
     ¦       #   Remove the first item
      ¨      #   As well as the last item
```

It'll always output an additional trailing empty list, because `Δ` will loop an additional time to determine if the list isn't changing anymore.

The determination of the depth of the multi-dimensional matrix (`` DdΔ€`}\N> ``) is taken from [this answer of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/240671/52210).

Minor note: `"ε¦¨"×` cannot be `…ε¦¨×` or `…ε¨¦×`, because the `¦¨`/`¨¦` will be interpret as [dictionary words](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) `"ink"`/`"keys"` respectively: [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOyc1sPLTu04vB0HS4IZ8WhZUDO//8A).

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 188 bytes

```
;{:G`
(\[)(\d+|\[((\[)|(?<-4>])|[^][])+(?(4)^)]),(?=(\d+|\[((\[)|(?<-7>])|[^][])+(?(7)^)]),)|(?<=,(\d+|(?(10)^)\[((])|(?<-10>\[)|[^][])+])),(\d+|\[((\[)|(?<-13>])|[^][])+(?(13)^)])(?=])
$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVbLTl0xDNzzHa10j0gl8nRSCiz5iMNBrdQuuumi6q78O7XHk1xuWXFIHGc8nnHu7x9/fv769nr78fT49fX27@fHr1enp307PX2/fnnaT/b9cnr48qncH9vL/nzsx3Z9ejiV7Xk7tnB6uHsXKZeR4pHYuwuI1tV4o8t26vBD8ebezvPYsW3hXd6YLxPHjMwK4diuPsTX133fS2hBjrBH/dv1bw45lEM/9hESVkoYuhL2pjsDOzkId3Jo@lfjQjqO40rztVAZ33W1hqhfQ@MiIqOeFGbpwfIkZG48Uw1FyMgZdc0jDYFGINJyCXA23Bp20Vu6ZvecTVFH7BuOikxNc2WeQQ1AuuttjkrzILtV7LWL7nTgjcjh@Lz2hjMD6IyDpBHYwloHokROE3HllU9WHQk7VnvESkeEZrMzzFcX7kFGhYw0cizcadzRCpCv6NnEiH4wof43@1BwXlCNd3swUwT2MxeGQnjGFaIxTOjffovnrcQxey/sh6AHtuOsuHqEHM98Hd/e00TlNNblndAs4KQiwnvVGFupDMfnFZs2BnFU7A4iFLBpK5OxiTBDT3ZmslvAoSU0ZOWCp2G3oa7IDmbuVDKYWHGnYqNXxXxTK4K6@nKZqbZwpeOv6dl2Kn0zFuvw7NR1DABHMA2W6Ag3sTp9Zi6jpk5j605i40yCU3igApfYd@U3RL/M7/GFwiwwrrDBheDN6jA/bSGQuRtez7LJ1pKxijPbD3xn5HSTZuAubJ3bfJAWq7RwfIzw1lqJmKrJ0c7P9iLGW2GVTIPAcrQEaKZYBkZI5QiIGHFtGS@tJg6Lx@0R48dvxICgCIwzWS1tYCpyHBqLsiQ4xxcysvKC78ie@Vj1ngnYibRlXetWj7HorFtNmcJtwbtTqYtChCO0N0N0AFWjIHXcQHLOW8H9ncoYHBQVjETqrYVpbosuq/ICXHn1Uzjait@B2w1rIiOTt7zMLzRwh95k6dtHmGEX7yxOY4yZnWH0uqp1VRayYCfSMn@iFQtyZiKPrnTW7Z6rVGiirTv0kqjD4bUu3jqc0@jBOdRxA0ePP15nXQx41n1agqzMXoew/5mPeQrem8SsUBa9kkJnnxr5ET6Fka5LuFmWFuIauRldTsunlQitusZedncA3V/g7PMjHfmkRX/a@QPDfwg0PoOGt66fB3hYlt7yhbc79QaXc8b4tHKnTT698gwPViqjEm9CFY0ac6elpZi6nNZ89s2Hhtgz6pDlusxvvyuuHw/R@f3vDp8jwslVUVPkvGjrwSro7HluYpovriJ587k5HdR9rh/HPw) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
;{:G`
```

Output the contents of the buffer before every iteration, but don't double-output the last iteration.

```
(\[)(\d+|\[((\[)|(?<-4>])|[^][])+(?(4)^)]),(?=(\d+|\[((\[)|(?<-7>])|[^][])+(?(7)^)]),)|
```

Match the first element in the array or one of its inner subarrays, as long as that array has at least three elements. The leading `[` is captured as that's slightly golfier than a lookbehind. The first element is matched normally and the second element is matched with a lookahead as if it's a subarray then we'll want to match the first element in the subarray. .NET balancing groups are used to ensure that whole subarrays are matched. Alternatively:

```
(?<=,(\d+|(?(10)^)\[((])|(?<-10>\[)|[^][])+])),(\d+|\[((\[)|(?<-13>])|[^][])+(?(13)^)])(?=])
```

Match the last element in the array or one of its inner subarrays, as long as that array has at least three elements. The penultimate element is matched with a lookbehind which is subtly different as it matches from right to left so `]`s increase the balancing group depth and `[`s decrease it. Here a lookahead is slightly golfier than capturing the trailing `]`.

```
$1
```

Keep the leading `[` before the first element if that's what we matched.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 66 bytes

```
Ｗ¬⁼θυ«≔∨υθθ⟦⭆¹θ⟧≔ＩＩθυ≔⟦υ⟧ηＦη«Ｆ‹²Ｌκ«≔⟦⟧ζＷκ⊞ζ⊟κＦ⮌✂ζ¹±¹⊞κμ»Ｆκ¿⁺⟦⟧λ⊞ηλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVZNb9swDD2nv8JHG8gO@rSEnYZht64LtmPQQ1C4cdCsaeKkAzr0t2eWyCfaQwO3jSnyiXyknvrQb04Ph83@ev3T7/ZdVd8dzvW342WzH@rjsro0TVP9vVl8GYbd9rn@caovy@rYpJ/PN4vVafd8rte/zuPf7ffNS63Swn1a4oCvm@FMv45Nk@BkaX25X1Z9MjweTlXd533o@203DLVeVrfd8/bc10@cxKKEjpFvKXKx4Kyfmmp1Gfr6bVmtDi8pIq9mtJ/da3cauvrXfvfQJY8xy7tuuzl3tWoSdI58Wla/c9A7shgxd49VvdpfhrzjHq59@j66vt@8X6/r9BkRQ8Ztxy@j63pM3udHsyEuK5vfzPgkw@g82lwOdMng81rMTvo@WdYhv7j85CCTfQKBi8GJwSLEsEFPMCzB2pwLJdBykMk2w9maXAnV03K2Or85hqUtXY7yBNvmzGJ201JzpKIYVqHEyAZiwPI@pZ4URbAOPFomQedVolcxc8QU6nH5jZpik6HNSUUOIVxmhvoGMj3yjVxAm22BgQnBCA0R27hCg0anW86XSAlEKZPpZ@lFeAQmitpFKTuC9WiQYh8yWEpRiiRkbExdtNJnMqgyYtxjGbEW/VCcbUAu8CCOqJGYBWLKZHY52zJDTsbdSokRAxTZQ8PDMmygIc4wdtI0i5SDDDxjczYW/TdCd5CKCMBO2bWoycwGkfi0HOQR55gogz77/5tmypEoQUpqsjIcqhwQ3ocAeTAZVoG5QLAGJw9kluNphW5CwUkLE1ZQT4QguTILCq0Et0XWnJxXgm0Z1oMHJcPBXE6aFqBBXrTOCrsap6rlfDUmeT7ukfUS8mhRJzYvvLQyzDRFQdTQikZpLNsijw70Y6L8pCWoWhcpYxQFoibTrYiu0jQt@l7k0UmJxJqXIQxFNkSXLVTWFxI84qJMFPXBcvoeBlwJDmU78aDrqJ2fNPOBzAY5aRrzglui3EbQsUlbwa6B1jkZeCdVa5Di5WAVHdOzI@GmOubL1cdUBfTIsiHiOE6EzYih5KXKLLDeEtCHuRT5b@V6cmBKibp7vp4gN2F2jzjMoJ6hGLmcisjFmSAF/L8wfq6fXvf/AA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｗ¬⁼θυ«
```

Repeat until the array stops changing.

```
≔∨υθθ
```

Except on the first run, use the new array in place of the original.

```
⟦⭆¹θ⟧
```

Pretty-print the array on its own line.

```
≔ＩＩθυ
```

Deep clone the array. (Unfortunately adding `0` or multiplying by `1` doesn't work because those operators only vectorise once.)

```
≔⟦υ⟧ηＦη«
```

Start processing the array and all of its subarrays.

```
Ｆ‹²Ｌκ«
```

If this array has at least three elements, then...

```
≔⟦⟧ζＷκ⊞ζ⊟κ
```

... remove the elements of the array into a temporary array, and...

```
Ｆ⮌✂ζ¹±¹⊞κμ
```

... push all of the elements of the temporary array except the first and last back to the array.

```
»Ｆκ¿⁺⟦⟧λ⊞ηλ
```

Push all subarrays of the current array to the list of arrays to be processed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 68 bytes

```python
def f(L):L>f<map(f,L)<L.pop(0)+L.pop()
L=input()
while[f(L)]:print L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVbtittADPzfp/DPhJrS3ZX247j2CfwGIT8KvXCBNmdKSunTp/ZKI9nlDnPY8mosjWZnM/@9v77d4uPx/eUyXA7T8Wn6enn@@W0@XMbp@Dx9mt/mw@fjR7k5fpi@XG/z7/ty9@f1@uPltKacn@Zf19t9mB6P0/IXxqGOw/K/LDfncTjFccj9ihpo40D9KS3XGlgWLzHuibwGcn/X@qJ4XiOn2h@4Xz0p9TVVwD3AHiCkJA3EDQYJLPVapICiSanHklabeifST9FqY39ihZVPcs/KAlt6Za0vi95zk6YUNqDFpgFhgPQ71s@aJbAMHklJiP2t0BuUOWEK/XB/kqHQGii9qKYpgqvMyNxAZka9TRsoPVYVWBCS09DwGTYaIiZdtF4hpQqlSmbeldewoipRMi4pmQU2Y0BB10iApERvUpDxYZki@ZwlEExiOmOXWME8glZbUQtWCEcySGhBmEqdXa3WNMQud/IWGwTUdEXEClLYKiLuMLQZGqHk6oJXbK2GMP/kdFfvSABoyy6hp7QTovBJmpSRx0pUwpzz/0NLtiUsKXhP5OIItkH0OwKowlTYAOaqwCbsPJBp25OcbkHBTqsbVtBPgyGxaSFglODWbI19vwpsUdgMHoKLQ7ncDK3Cg7J7HTm7EbuqaL0RSt7Lvalfwh4JfeLjxktxMYuKqrshuUdFvCazRwb9UFTejARdR7MyRQkgaqPuIHTZ0KL7u9kje4vCWnYRVrMN92WCy2YjISOvuaJkDqTlZwRwJDDaZl8hx1HZ77T0js1W32kResEpYacRfGwzVrCb4HXsgmfvOoKU7BvLfCzutgRvfSzb0adUVcyINNCwHTfGljxgdQXTgvqtAL1bi9l/8eOJwVRwd896PMFu6u4cYWgw7lCSH05mcm1nSBW/F87nfw)

A program taking input from STDIN and output to STDOUT. Doesn't output the initial array. Terminates with error.